# Streaming and filtering by a sub class

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to use Java streams to filter out a base vehicle class that has car, motorbike, etc. sub classes. There is a parameter called vehicleType that can be CAR, MOTORBIKE, etc. I am trying to create a streaming filter in such a way that List<BaseVehicleEntity<?>> vehicleEntities contains only cars if the vehicleType is CAR, or if vehicleType is anything else, I filter out everything that ISN'T a CAR.

I have tried the following code, but it isn't working. My compiler gives a warning that the second .filter() is being ignored, so I am doing something wrong.

```
List<BaseVehicleEntity<?>> vehicleEntities = findTasks();

if (vehicleType.equals("CAR")) {
    vehicleEntities.stream()
            .filter(obj -> obj instanceof CarEntity)
            .map(obj -> (CarEntity) obj)
            .filter(obj -> obj.getVehicleType().equals("CAR"));
} else vehicleEntities.stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj instanceof CarEntity)
        .map(obj -> (CarEntity) obj)
        .filter(obj -> !obj.getVehicleType().equals("CAR"));
```

Comment: Why do you need second .filter()? *if (vehicleType.equals("CAR"))* itself is filtering the entities which are CAR & NOT CAR

Comment: In both cases, there is no terminal operation like forEach/Collect.
I guess that it's why the IDE is complaining

Comment: Is it so that a `CarEntity` always has type `CAR` and there are other entity types for `MOTORBIKE` etc.? Or are all vehicles of type `CarEntity`? The latter would be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, a terminal operation such as `collect(Collectors.toList())` needs to be added to return the filtered list.

The requested functionality may be implemented using a separate `Predicate` to filter the cars depending on `vehicleType` as follows:

```java
public static List<BaseVehicleEntity> filterByCar(String vehicleType, List<BaseVehicleEntity> vehicles) {

    Predicate<CarEntity> condition = (car) -> "CAR".equals(car.getVehicleType());
    if (!"CAR".equals(vehicleType)) {
        condition = condition.negate();
    }
    return vehicles.stream()
            .filter(v -> v instanceof CarEntity)
            .map(CarEntity.class::cast)
            .filter(condition)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Example test (`LightCar` and `HeavyCar` extend `CarEntity`, `HeavyCar` has vehicle type = `"SUV"`):

```java
System.out.println(filterByCar("CAR", Arrays.asList(
        new CarEntity(), new MotorbikeEntity(), new LightCar(), new HeavyCar())));

System.out.println(filterByCar("NOTCAR", Arrays.asList(
        new CarEntity(), new MotorbikeEntity(), new LightCar(), new HeavyCar())));
```

Output:

```
[CarEntity: CAR, LightCar: CAR]
[HeavyCar: SUV]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a terminal operation like .collect or .reduce.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is that you doesn't collect your filtered collection. `filter` and `map` not terminal operations in stream api. So I could suggest next thing:

```
List<BaseVehicleEntity<?>> vehicleEntities = findTasks();
if (vehicleType.equals("CAR")) {
    List<CarEntity> cars = vehicleEntities.stream()
            .filter(obj -> obj instanceof CarEntity)
            .map(obj -> (CarEntity) obj)
            .filter(obj -> obj.getVehicleType().equals("CAR"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
    List<CarEntity> notCars = vehicleEntities.stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj instanceof CarEntity)
        .map(obj -> (CarEntity) obj)
        .filter(obj -> !obj.getVehicleType().equals("CAR"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

More information could be found [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/streams.html#terminal-and-non-terminal-operations)

Comment: If I had .collect(Collectors.toList()); the IDE still gives a warning that the line where that happens is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, a stream must have a terminal operator to actually do anything; terminal operators are e.g. [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) or [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). Notice the Javadocs, they mention that these are terminal operators explicitly. So, your code will actually do nothing until you collect it to a `List` (if a `List` is what you want - there are collectors for many standard collection types, e.g. [`toSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--)):

```java
List<CarEntity> cars = vehicleEntities.stream()
            .filter(obj -> obj instanceof CarEntity)
            .map(obj -> (CarEntity) obj)
            .filter(obj -> obj.getVehicleType().equals("CAR"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also consider the [`partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) collector, which will split the list according to your predicate in a single traversal.